# Install Yosemite on partition in new computer

Tags: macos

Currently using Yosemite on older computer. Want to continue using Adobe cs5 apps which don't work past Yosemite. Don't remember how I installed it but not purchased and don't have installer. Anybody know where I can get installer. Can I install from backup of current computer?

Comment: Not quite clear from your question... but if you mean can you install an old OS on a new Mac, the answer is... no. Not possible other than as a VM. If you mean 'How do I acquire an old Adobe installer?', that would best be addressed to Adobe.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) On what basis do you believe that Adobe CS5 doesn't work on Macs running a macOS version higher than Yosemite? I've seen Adobe CS5 work on all versions of macOS up until macOS Sierra. I'm **not** saying it won't work on macOS High Sierra, just that I haven't personally seen it installed on a High Sierra machine.